# I want to update specific fields in PostgreSQL only if they are null

Tags: database, postgresql, timescaledb

I was looking to update fields on a row in PostgreSQL only if the fields were null. Otherwise I would overwrite what's already in the row.
My `update` looks as simple as this:

```
UPDATE public.people
    SET flag=$flag,
    name=$name,
    surname=$surname
    WHERE id_dt=$id_dt;
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
UPDATE public.people
    SET flag=$flag,
    name=coalesce(name,$name),
    surname=coalesce(surname,$surname)
    WHERE id_dt=$id_dt
```

**Coalesce()** returns the first non-null value, so `name` if it's already there, or `$name` (that is your *new* value)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could start a transaction with 2 statemnts and add a where clause that ignores correct rows:

```sql
BEGIN;
UPDATE public.people
    SET flag = $flag,
    name = $name
    WHERE id_dt=$id_dt
    AND name IS NULL;

UPDATE public.people
    SET flag = $flag,
    surname = $surname
    WHERE id_dt=$id_dt
    AND surname IS NULL;
COMMIT;
```

If you go with the coalesce option like stated in a simpling answer, you can still add a `where name is null or surname is null` clause to reduce the working set.

Side note: I see you use `$` like it was used in string interpolation. Always prefer to use prepared statements to avoid attacks via sql injection.